# Can I execute R code files from within C#?

Tags: c#, r

I have an R source file.

I want to execute the code in that file within my C# app.

The `.R` file has a function that looks like this:

How can I execute the `.R` file from my console app and pass in the parameters for the function?

Comment: Given your specific example you seem to be dealing with a Shiny app. There’s probably a simpler way of specifically invoking Shiny apps from C# than there is for generic R code. That said, there’s the [“R.NET” library](https://www.nuget.org/packages/R.NET/), which does pretty much exactly what you want.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [rdotnet(R.NET)](https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=rdotnet)

> R.NET enables .NET Framework to collaborate with R statistical
>   computing. R.NET requires .NET Framework 4 and native DLLs installed
>   with R environment. You need no other extra installations. Enjoy
>   statistics and programming in your special language with R.
>
> https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=rdotnet

```
        REngine.SetEnvironmentVariables();
        REngine engine = REngine.GetInstance();
        engine.Initialize();
        //string path = "\HelloWorld.r";
        //engine.Evaluate("source('" + path + "')");
        var x = engine.Evaluate("x <- 1 + 2");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can invoke the script file with your application.

http://jmp75.github.io/rdotnet/

`engine.Evaluate("source('c:/src/path/to/myscript.r')");`